# Series $\sum_k 1/(k (m k^2 - 1))$

Tags: sequences-and-series

From Gradshteyn & Ryzhnik Table of Integrals, 0.236 we know that

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(4k^2-1)}&=\ln 4 -1,\\
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(9k^2-1)}&=\frac32(\ln 3 -1),\\
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(36k^2-1)}&=-3+\frac32\ln 3+2\ln2.
\end{align}

My question: How where the three above sums calculated and more generally, is there a simplification of the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(nk^2-1)}$$
for a parameter $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: 4, 9, and 36 are squares. Maybe on should restrict attention to parameters $n$ that are squares?

Answer (score 0):

Applying partial fractions will give you

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(t^2k^2-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t/2}{tk-1}+\frac{t/2}{tk+1}-\frac1k$$

which can then be tackled using the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) to get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(t^2k^2-1)}=-\gamma-\frac{\psi(1/t)+\psi(-1/t)}2$$

which can be reduced using the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) to

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(t^2k^2-1)}=-\gamma-\frac t2-\frac\pi2\cot\left(\frac\pi t\right)-\psi\left(\frac1t\right)$$

from which the results may be deduced using [Gauss's digamma theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss's_digamma_theorem) as long as $t$ is rational. For example, with $t=6$ we have

\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(36k^2-1)}&=-3+\ln(12)-2\left[\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)\ln\sin\left(\frac\pi6\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)\ln\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)\right]\\&=-3+\ln(12)-2\left[\frac12\ln\left(\frac12\right)-\frac12\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\right]\\&=-3+2\ln(2)+\frac32\ln(3)\end{align}